# not getting value of file in php

Tags: php

I have problem with getting name of image.
I have use following code to update image under upload folder.
I am updating image path with  `$image= time()."_".strtolower(str_replace($tokan, "" ,$file));`

time function use to add time stamp before image name.
but problem is only time_ path update I did not get the file name in that.

for example:
if I am browsing image using file type like sunset.jpg
I only get "time_" not sunset.jpg...

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; 
    $username="root"; 
    $password=""; 
    $db="training_swapnil"; 
    $tbl="gallary"; 
    $tb="album";
    $img_id=$_GET['id'];
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");
    $q="SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE eid='$img_id'";
    $r=mysql_query($q);
    $rw= mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
    echo $img=stripslashes($rw['image']);?>                

  <form name="update_img">
    <table border="0"><tr>
     <td><label>Uploaded Image:</label></td>
      <td><?php echo "<img src=\"uploads/$img\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" />";?></td></tr>
       <tr><td><label>Upload New Image:</label></td><td>    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"></td></tr>

    <?php     
         echo"here in post";
         $file=$_POST['file'];
        //$str=$HTTP_POST_FILES['file']['name'];
          echo "str file =$str";
         $tokan = array(" ", "'","`","’");
        //$image= time().".$file.";         
        $image= time()."_".strtolower(str_replace($tokan, "" ,$file));
        $path= "uploads/".$image;
        echo "path using file=$image";
        $sql="UPDATE gallary  set image='$image', path='$path' WHERE eid='$img_id'"; 
        echo $sql;
        $res=mysql_query($sql);
        $res=mysql_query($s);
            if($res>0)
        {
            if($file !=none)
            {                                      if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path))              {                                               //header("location:viewalbum.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
 }
?>
</table></form>
```

Comment: You're open to both file-traversal attacks and SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$file=$_POST['file']` by `$file=$_FILES['file']['name']`

More details here : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1):

Replace your form tag with this one.

```
<form name="update_img" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You are missing **enctype="multipart/form-data"** attribute in your form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely not prepared to go live anywhere, there are huge security problems. For example, $img_id is not sanitized, etc.

Anyway, start by setting the form to actually accept file uploads, by setting it to multipart data, like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...
```